# Ordered List in Google App Engine - JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, list, jpa

Comics object can have many Chapter object.

I have this in `Comics` class:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Chapter.class, mappedBy="comics", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Chapter> chapters = null;
```

My method in adding a chapter to a Comics:

```
public Chapter addChapter(Chapter chapter, String key) {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    Comics comics = null;
    try{
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        comics = em.find(Comics.class, KeyFactory.stringToKey(key));
        chapter.setPages( new LinkedList<Page>() );

        comics.getChapters().add(chapter);

        tx.commit();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(tx != null && tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }

    return chapter;
}
```

My method for reading a Comics:

```
public Comics read(String key) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Comics comics = new Comics();
    try{
        Comics emComics = em.find(Comics.class, KeyFactory.stringToKey(key));
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(comics, emComics);
        comics.setChapters(new LinkedList<Chapter> (emComics.getChapters()));

    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
    return comics;
}
```

When I saved new `Comics`, I also have:

```
comics.setChapters( new LinkedList<Chapter>() );
```

The problem is that `read` method return unexpected ordering of `chapters`. What would be the best approach to display `chapters` in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **@OrderBy** annotation:

For example:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Chapter.class, mappedBy="comics", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@OrderBy("chapterNumber")
private List<Chapter> chapters = null;
```

This is assuming there is a **chapterNumber** field which is comparable

Comment: how do you move & delete the element in list?
I moved using chapterNumber successfully. But on delete even though i set the chapterNumber right for the remaining entities the fetch fails to retrieve the rest correctly.